# Select2 submitting value instead of id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I have Rails app, where I'm able to select country from:

`= f.input :country, label: t("heading.country"), as: :string, input_html: { class: 'select2', data: { allowadd: true, depth: 0, id: @post.location.country.id, url: search_locations_path } }`

Select2 is attached to this element by:

```
loadSelect2 = (selector = '.select2') ->
  $(@).select2
    ajax:
      data: (term, page) ->
        search: term
        depth: $(@).data('depth')
      results: (data, page) ->
        results: data
      url: $(@).data('url')
    createSearchChoice: (term, data) ->
      if $(data).filter(->
        @title.localeCompare(term) is 0
      ).length is 0
        id: term
        title: term
    createSearchChoicePosition: 'bottom'
    formatResult: (item) ->
      item.title
    formatSelection: (item) ->
      item.title
    initSelection: (element, callback) ->
      callback
        id: $(element).data('id')
        title: $(element).val()
```

So, as you see, I'm able to select country or add one (if there is no country available). Also I'm loading initial value from input's `val` and id from `data-id` inside `initSelection`.

When I select country and submit the form everything works: `post_params['country']` is equal to selected country's id, but if I submit form without changing selected value (leaving the default one), then `post_params['country']` helds `value`, instead of `id`.

Where am I wrong and how to fix that?

Comment: where rails code creating the input?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ added code creating the input

Comment: it seems that the input isn't a collection

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ what do you mean? Input is a single value, more is loaded via ajax call, which returns array: [{id: 1, title: 'France'}, {id: 2, title: 'Germany'}, ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input to:

`= f.input :country, label: t("heading.country"), as: :string, input_html: { value: @post.location.country.id, class: 'select2', data: { allowadd: true, depth: 0, title: @post.location.country.title, url: search_locations_path } }`

...so that in the input's value you will store `id` of initially selected element and in data attributes instead of `data-id` you will store element's title `data-title` (of course you can leave `data-id` intact for future use).
Also you need to refactor `initSelection` function to use those new values as of:

`initSelection: (element, callback) ->
      callback
        id: $(element).val(),
        title: $(element).data('title')`